# telnet/nc unable to send packet after few packets

Tags: linux, tcp, redhat, tcpdump, netcat

I am facing very strange behaviour in TCP connection. 
Created listener with following command:

> ncat -4 -l 10000

Sending data:

> telnet Public-IP 10000

Analysing data with `tcpdump` and check connection status with `netstat`. When I am sending data packet (1,2,3,4,5 .... so on). At server side only 4 or 5 packets received then nothing happens.
tcpdump is not showing any coming packets while netstat is showing "Established" connection stat.

Same thing happen with `ncat public-ip 10000` command, ehrn use it as a client.

When I will exit with telnet command wih `^] and quit`, then telnet is unable to connect with server(Error: Connection refused by remote host). If I will kill `ncat -4 -l 10000` command and restart again then connection will be established from client (telnet) and server will received only 4-5 packets.

I have cross checked all tcp parameters by [this url](http://www.linux-admins.net/2010/09/linux-tcp-tuning.html)

Can anybody have idea what is happening at server-end and how can I debug it?

EDIT:1:

TCPDUMP at client machine

```
//Data-pkt-3
    13:26:55.844538 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 37219, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 55)
        10.240.8.230.53839 > PUBLIC-IP.PORT: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9660 (correct), seq 9:12, ack 4, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 301276907 ecr 436759593], length 3

   //Data-pkt-4 
    13:26:59.916512 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 37220, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 55)
        10.240.8.230.53839 > PUBLIC-IP.PORT: Flags [P.], cksum 0x8035 (correct), seq 12:15, ack 4, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 301277925 ecr 436763991], length 3
    13:27:00.179644 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 37221, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 55)
        10.240.8.230.53839 > PUBLIC-IP.PORT: Flags [P.], cksum 0x7ff3 (correct), seq 12:15, ack 4, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 301277991 ecr 436763991], length 3
    13:27:00.443650 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 37222, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 55)
        10.240.8.230.53839 > PUBLIC-IP.PORT: Flags [P.], cksum 0x7fb1 (correct), seq 12:15, ack 4, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 301278057 ecr 436763991], length 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure iptables is not blocking your connection:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Also verify you are capturing the correct interface in tcpdump

Run the following command to get the list of interfaces to use with tcpdump:

```
# ip a|grep :|egrep -v 'link|inet'|awk '{print $2}'|sed 's/://'
lo
enp0s31f6
wlp2s0
```

So your dcpdump commands to try would be (wired):

```
# tcpdump -i enp0s31f6
```

Or (wifi):

```
# tcpdump -i wlp2s0
```

The names of the interfaces on your Linux may be different.

Comment: tcpdump is getting for 4-5 packets then stop. I don't think iptables blocking it. If it's blocked by IPtables then no data packets would be received at server end.

Comment: Can you post tcpdump capture file?

Comment: The trace you posted is not detailed enough, use the tcpdump -w switch to save the capture into a file and open the file with Wireshark (or use Wireshark to capture).

In Wireshark there is an option Analyze > Follow > TCP Stream.

Use this option to get a visualization of the TCP session.